# numeric error in batch

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following code:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set HOUR=00
set MINS=10

if %HOUR% EQU 00 (
set HOUR=12
set /A minDiff=60-!MINS!&set expectedTime=1^.!minDiff!
)

echo expectedTime=!expectedTime!
```

The expected output that is the value of variable expectedTime must be 1.50 , but it outputs 1. only. The error given is:
Invalid number.Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
Please help!! 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted works fine for me. I suspect you got your error under slightly different conditions than what you posted.

SET /A has a very unfortunate feature in that any number that has a leading 0 is treated as octal notation. So a value of 08 or 09 is not a valid number for SET /A, and will give the error message that you cited. To get the correct value you must represent the MINS as 8 or 9 (no leading 0). Note that 00 through 07 work fine because both octal and decimal interpretation yield the same value.

One trick that is often used to deal with potential unwanted leading zeros is to prefix the numeric string with a suitably large power of 10 and then use the mod (remainder) operator to extract the desired value. For example, if you never expect a value larger than 9999, then you could use the following to safely deal with potential leading zeros in variable VAL

```
set /a "VAL=10000%VAL% %% 10000"
```

The nice thing about the above technique is it can be incorporated into a larger mathematical computation without having to seperately strip the leading zeros prior to the computation.

Answer (score -1):

Under the IF statement change to this:

```
 %HOUR% = 12
```

That should fix that issue.