# Batch Script set /a error

Tags: batch-file

How is this script keep on returning an error?

```
@echo off
set csd=Fri 03/08/2013
set edayn=%csd:~7,1%%csd:~8,1%
set /a tsday=%edayn%
echo %edayn%
echo %tsday%
pause
```

Time format: ddd mm/dd/yyyy
The "csd" variable is the day I opened the script.
To eliminate the zero on the variable "edayn" or the date, I used "set /a" to eliminate it
but it shows this error:

```
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
08
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When the day doesn't start with 0, it doesn't get this error.
I cannot find an error on this script

Comment: Just realized that there are two questions that are exactly the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077866/numeric-error-in-batch?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762794/invalid-number-numeric-constants-are-either-decimal-17-hexadecimal-0x11-o?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the /a in the SET just for assignment of a value to a variable :
`set tsday=%edayn%`

I get month and day from your csd with

```
%csd:~4,2%
%csd:~7,2%
```

**EDIT**
If you want to kill leading zeros, split each field into two parts (for tens and units), then for the tens field :-
 search and replace '0' with empty string '' using `%variable:0=%` syntax

```
@echo off
set csd=Fri 13/08/2013
set day1=%csd:~4,1%
set day2=%csd:~5,1%
set mo1=%csd:~7,1%
set mo2=%csd:~8,1%
set day=%day1:0=%%day2%
set mo=%mo1:0=%%mo2%
echo %day%/%mo%
```

Comment: But the normal `set` doesn't remove the leading zeros.

Comment: ah, yes, I was focussing on the error rather than the leading zero aspect :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error is because octal numbers (when the `/a` flag is used in the `set` command) are prefixed by the number 0 (zero).

The reason why `08` is not a valid number is because the octal number system contains only 8 symbols (0-7), which means that `08` isn't possible.

Comment: @Joey I didn't get the joke/reference/thing. Mind explaining?

Comment: Octadecimal would be base 18, you probably mean octal, which is base 8 :-)

Comment: @Joey edited it, a bit sad I didn't get best answer for solving the mystery :'(